# Wavelet transformation in python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, wavelet

I am trying to find a similar command of `dwt2` of matlab in python. I know that the following command convert 1D-array via wavelet:

```
import pywt
cA, cD = pywt.dwt([1D-array], 'db1')
```

I have *5000*784* array consisting of *5000* images converted to one row with *784* dimensions. When I use `dwt2` in matlab, it convert the matrix into *5000*196* array. To use python,  I have two difficulties:

(1) `pywt.dwt` needs 1D-array, however I have 2D  *5000*786* matrix.

(2) After applying `pywt.dwt`, it reduces the dimensionality into half of the previous one, however in matlab, it reduces into *196* dimension.

Comment: Have you tried [PyWavelets dwt2](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/ref/2d-dwt-and-idwt.html)?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, but it reduces _5000*784_ to _2500*392_, while we have _5000_ images. We want _5000*392_.

Comment: In your question, you say you're using `dwt2` in matlab, but `dwt` in python. Are you using a 2D transform in Matlab, but just a 1D transform in python? Posting a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help clarify.